# How do I make wamp shows every single error?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I uploaded my website from a wamp local server to a web host. Despite the fact that  my local php.ini was setup to `error_reporting = E_ALL`, when I uploaded the page on the web host, it shows me errors that wamp didn't, like :

> "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cookie - headers already sent by ..."

My question is, if it is possible, how do I setup my wamp server to show me all those errors to?

Comment: You probably have `output_buffering` turned on in your local php.ini

Comment: Go to the [PHP tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) scroll down to the section where it says _I have a typical "does not work" problem_. Follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E_ALL would show:

> "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cookie - headers already sent by ..."

However, if in your php.ini you have output buffering set to on, and on the other you have output buffering off, it can cause such errors to appear!

You want to configure BOTH with practically the same php.ini settings (obviously with server specific settings instead such as different tmp paths etc). You don't really want E_STRICT on a production server because it wont generally be an error but more of a recommendation.

**Update**

Forgot to mention, you will also need to `set display_errors = on` in php.ini but on production that should be off and logging used instead. For more information that explains all the error settings: http://www.phpknowhow.com/configuration/php-ini-error-settings/

Comment: Meh even the output buffering off, it still doesn't show the errors.

Comment: Sorry, just updated my answer, does that help now?